# Not able to pass a primitive value to my custom SOAPHandler class

Tags: java

I have written custom soaphandler class which extends javax.xml.rpc.GenericHandler. And my requirement is to pass a primitive variable into this handler class from my other caller java class. This variable should pass at run time and should be thread safe because multiple thread is going to access that handler same time.

I tried to store the value into  HandlerConfig object and injected it to the HandlerInfo, but I couldn't found this value in my handler.

This Soap Handler concept is new for me, so please help me to fix this issue.
below I'm posting my raw code for handler class and the class from where I'm calling it.

```
public class MilerHandler extends GenericHandler {

    private HandlerInfo info;
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
    private static final String DATE = "Date";
    private static final String URI = "http://-----.com";
   public MilerHandler() {
         }

    public void init(HandlerInfo info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public QName[] getHeaders() {
        return info.getHeaders();
    }

    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext context) {
        SOAPMessageContext smc = (SOAPMessageContext)context;
        SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
        try {
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = smc.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
            SOAPFactory factory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();

            SOAPElement authorization =  factory.createElement(AUTHORIZATION, PCMilerClientService.PREFIX, URI);
            SOAPElement date = factory.createElement(DATE, PCMilerClientService.PREFIX, URI);
            authorization.addTextNode((String)value1); //Value1 need to be pass from my business class.
            date.addTextNode((int)value2);          //Value2 need to be pass from my business class.
            SOAPElement authHeader = factory.createElement(PCMilerClientService.AUTH_HEADER, PCMilerClientService.PREFIX, URI);
            authHeader.addChildElement(authorization);
            authHeader.addChildElement(date);
            SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
            header.addChildElement(authHeader);
            message.saveChanges();
            if(log.debug()) {
                log.debug(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleResponse(javax.xml.rpc.handler.MessageContext context) {
        SOAPMessageContext smc = (SOAPMessageContext)context;
        SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
        if(log.debug()) {
            log.debug(message);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleFault(javax.xml.rpc.handler.MessageContext context) {
        SOAPMessageContext smc = (SOAPMessageContext)context;
        SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
        if(log.debug()) {
            log.debug(message);
        }
        return true;
    }
}



public class MilerDistanceLookupWorker  {

    public void run() {
        IService_Stub stub = null;
        Service_Impl impl = null;
        try {
                impl = new Service_Impl();
                setPCMilerHandler(impl);
                stub = (IService_Stub) impl.getBasicHttpBinding_IService();
                  } catch (ServiceException e) {
            -----------------
        }
    }

    private void setMilerHandler(Service_Impl impl) {
    HandlerInfo handlerInfo = new HandlerInfo();
        handlerInfo.setHandlerClass(MilerHandler.class);
        QName authHeader = new QName(NAMESPACE, AUTH_HEADER, PREFIX);
        List<HandlerInfo> headerList = impl.getHandlerRegistry().getHandlerChain(authHeader);
        headerList.add(handlerInfo);
        impl.getHandlerRegistry().setHandlerChain(authHeader, headerList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add information about the problem you ran into. Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and a stacktrace if you're encountering an Exception.

Comment: I simply want pass string value to this MilerHandler class at runtime which I can simply set into soap header element. And this header element is authentications details but not a simple username and password, instead it is runtime generated hashcode and a timestamp. So either I generate this hashcode in this class or in my business class but in both case I need to pass some value into my handler class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to implement SOAP auth handler then you need to do something like this:

```
public class SOAPAuthenticationHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public SOAPAuthenticationHandler (String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
        Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) smc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if (!outboundProperty) {
            return outboundProperty;
        }
        try {
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = smc.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
            SOAPHeader header = envelope.addHeader();
            SOAPElement security = header.addChildElement("Security", "wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
            security.addNamespaceDeclaration("common", "some xmlns");
            SOAPElement usernameToken = security.addChildElement("UsernameToken", "wsse");
            usernameToken.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:wsu"), "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
            SOAPElement usernameElement = usernameToken.addChildElement("Username", "wsse");
            usernameElement.addTextNode(username);
            SOAPElement passwordElement = usernameToken.addChildElement("PasswordSaltedDigest", "common");
            passwordElement.setAttribute("Type", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gostr341194");
            passwordElement.addTextNode(password);
        } catch (SOAPException | DOMException e) {
            getLogger().error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return outboundProperty;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And after that you need to add this handler to port' `HandlerChain`:

```
List handlerChain = ((BindingProvider) port).getBinding().getHandlerChain();
if (handlerChain == null) {
    handlerChain = new ArrayList();
}
handlerChain.add(new SOAPAuthenticationHandler(username, password));
((BindingProvider) port).getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlerChain);
```